# How to make dynamic timestamp in ffpmeg, not static?

Tags: dynamic, time, batch-file, ffmpeg, timestamp

I am using ffmpeg (windows pc) with my webcam to record what happens when i'm out of home.
It works fine, but i can't make dynamic clock and date on screen.
I have tried

```
-vf "[in]drawtext=fontsize=12:fontfile=arial.ttf:text='%date%':x=10:y=25,  
drawtext=fontsize=12:fontfile=arial.ttf:text="%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%"
```

It works, but it shows time only for start moment, than it wont change during video recording.
it looks like:[image]
Is there any method to out time on screen?
Thanks.

Comment: [Does this work](http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/)?  That guide is written for Linux it appears, but I'm curious to know whether the same syntax is supported by Windows `ffmpeg`.  If `\%T` doesn't work, try `%%T` to specify a literal `%` sign.

Comment: Thanks, rojo, but it dont works. My code in question is working, but time dont ticking. Seems like it uses %time% once, and thats all.

Comment: I've [read](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/08/ffmpeg-add-timestamp-windows/) that the `drawtext` video filter in Windows ffmpeg supports [printf style time syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Rojo, thank you very much!  You can write it like answer, and get some karma :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've [read](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/08/ffmpeg-add-timestamp-windows/) that the `drawtext` video filter in Windows ffmpeg supports [printf style time syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).